Is there any standard for wire nut sizes?
I am looking for the old school nuts to screw in three 12 gauge wires. They were usually red and kind of beefy.  When buying combination packs of nuts even the largest were well too small.  So to try to find the larger ones I purchased 10 gauge nuts. They're still too small.  Is there not any standard for these things - so that 10 gauge is not just a sales pitch but a specific dimension?


You need to look more closely at the specifications of minimum and maximum (number of) (size of) wires combinations. I'm not sure if color codes are consistent around the world (seems unlikely!), but the big red ones still exist in the US and should be rated for up to 4 12-gauge wires (minimum 2 14-gauge).

And, personally, I would go more for a lever-style such as Wago, particularly for more than 2 wires - just had too many problems with wire nuts over the years...

@JonCuster. I usually do the Wago but I do work with (a very good) old school electrician that insists on the nuts.

First of all, for anything permanently attached to 120V (or higher) circuits in the US/Canada, everything must be properly listed for that use. Typically that means UL or ETL. There are other possibilities, but NOT: CE (that means some things in some places but not generally in the US), TM (trademark), FCC (radio frequency issues). I have a hunch, but can't tell for sure, that the Amazon example shown is NOT UL or ETL listed.
As far as the actual sizes, most usage is shown on the package. There are some general color codes in use. I am pretty sure they were basically set - as an arbitrary manufacturer decision - by Ideal and then copied by others. But as far as I know there are no true standards. Purple is fairly consistently used for copper/aluminum connections and an inspector may look for that where relevant, but otherwise anything goes.
The big name is Ideal. They have a catalog that lists everything. For example, the 451 Yellow can take a minimum of 2 x 18 AWG and a maximum of 3 x 12 AWG. The 74B Yellow can take a minimum of 2 x 18 AWG and a maximum of 4 x 14 AWG + 1 18 AWG. The 452 Red can take a minimum of 2 x 18 AWG and a maximum of 4 x 10 AWG. The 76B Red can take a minimum of 2 x 14 AWG and a maximum of 4 x 12 AWG. So there is some variance, but yellow and red, in general, will cover most of the common residential wiring including thermostat (18 AWG), 15A (14 AWG) and 20A (12 AWG) circuits.
It is best, when possible, to stick in the middle of the range of a particular wire nut's capability. So if you have 4 x 14 AWG you can use a 74B but a 76B may be a better choice. On the other hand, if you have only 2 x 14 AWG you may be better off with the 74B.
Ideal also has the BT2 which is designed for "the entire range of red and yellow connectors" - 2 x 18 AWG to 2 x 8 AWG - i.e., one item that you can use for everything from thermostat wires to 15A/20A circuits to water heaters to ovens. Presumably costs a little more but for someone doing a lot of work it can be worth it to not worry about which wire nut to pick for each task.
Clearly since the exact specifications vary by both color and type within Ideal, about the only thing you can count on is the sequence - in the case of Ideal, and copied (but not guaranteed to be copied) by others: gray, blue, orange, yellow, red, blue. Yes, blue is listed twice. Why? There aren't that many colors that can be distinguished really quickly and in varying lighting conditions. Each particular type of wire nut only has blue as small or large, and they are far enough apart that it would be very hard to confuse them.

quite comprehensive answer - I had not thought to check for "US" or "ETL".  What is their relationship to Underwriters Laboratory / UL ?  I'll check out BT2

Typo - should be UL. Fixed.

C’mon: they say they’re UL cerified in a picture. Granted, there’s nothing on the packaging, but how come all the doubts? /s

Despite all the other typical Chinglish, and the diagram of How to Use which doesn't show any twisting, I suspect that "UL Cerified" may be a deliberate misspelling - if you don't say "UL Listed" or "UL Certified" then UL can't go after you for saying that it is certified or listed. "Cerified" is a meaningless term. Then again, they may just not care. But in any case, I would not use them - who knows what could go wrong.

Wire nuts are typically rated for specific combinations of wire sizes.  Example (see wire sizes and combinations): https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/62/623f53b0-77f3-49b8-9ef8-1f9e42c7388a.pdf
YMMV if you use them for sizes and/or combinations that aren't listed.

Nice! The 452 (red!) appears to be the one I've been hunting. It is rated for 1 to 5 12 gauge wries.
